# extract values which are not blank from a column in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have tried all similar posts to try and get this working, but nothing I try seems to work!

I have a list with values in on a sheet called "All" which contains vales generated from a formula, these can show as text or as blank

```
        D
5     text
6   
7     text
8     text2
9
10    text
```

I would like this list generated on a different sheet ("Summary")  so it just shows the values eg:

```
     A
 1  text
 2  text
 3  text2
 4  text
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`=IFERROR(INDEX(D:D,SMALL(IF(D:D<>"",ROW(D:D)),ROW(1:1)),"")`

This is an array formula, confirm the formula using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

If you can limit the size of D:D to exact ranges that would increase performance.

---

**EDIT**

*OP Comment:-*

Not sure what I was doing wrong, simply changing it to `=IFERROR(INDEX('All'!D5:D50,SMALL(IF('All'!D5:D50<>"",ROW('All'!D5:D50)),ROW('All'!5:5))),"")` - have I missed something obvious?

*Response:-*

`=IFERROR(INDEX('All'!D$5:D$50,SMALL(IF('All'!D$5:D$50<>"",ROW('All'!D$5:D$50)-ROW('All'!D$5)+1),ROW(1:1))),"")`

That's almost correct but so that you can understand what is going on here I'll break the formula down for you. For starters, you need to use absolute referencing to **lock the rows off** so they don't change when you drag the formula down.

`IF('All'!D$5:D$50<>"",ROW('All'!D$5:D$50)-ROW('All'!D$5)+1)`

The above formula is building an array of row numbers that we want INDEX to return, I have added the logic `-ROW('All'!D$5)+1` to ensure that the first row of the data will be the first row in `INDEX()`; The array returns either a row number or `FALSE`.

`SMALL([above],ROW(1:1))`

We then use `SMALL()` to return the nth smallest value in the array of row numbers, this has to start as `ROW(1:1)` as that returns 1 and will get us the first match. This formula cannot be locked off so that it changes as it is dragged down, returning the 2nd/3rd/4th etc.

`IFERROR(INDEX('All'!D$5:D$50,[above]),"")`

The `INDEX()` formula can now get the correct result based on the range and return the nth smallest match providing it exists, if there is no match it will throw an error which is why I have wrapped it in an `IFERROR()` to catch that and return `""` instead...

Comment: Thanks very much for the speedy reply! I have managed to adapt this to work, however originally the row needed to start counting from row 5 (would this be done by specifying ROW(5:5)?). Also limiting the D:D didn't seem to work for me either. Not sure what I was doing wrong, simply changing it to `=IFERROR(INDEX('All'!D5:D50,SMALL(IF('All'!D5:D50<>"",ROW('All'!D5:D50)),ROW('All'!5:5))),"")`  - have I missed something obvious?

Comment: @hsquared You're welcome! Please see my edit, I hope this helps.

Comment: You legend; thank you so much for taking the time to explain that through! It really helped a lot! :)